# dd a compressed *.xz image into a partition

Tags: beagleboneblack, dd, xz

I'm trying to copy a compressed image into a partition inside a Beaglebone.
Usually, it is a 2 step process:

```
xz -d console.img.xz # console.img is created
dd if=console.img of=/dev/mmcblk0p3
```

Is there a way, I can do it in a single step without uncompressing the file `*.img.xz`? This is because after uncompressed the image, it is too big for the current partition.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This seems to work, if that is what you mean:

```
xz -d < console.img.xz - | dd of=/dev/mmcblk0p3
```

Comment: Would that be `xz -d -  < console.img.xz | dd of=/dev/mmcblk0p3` instead?
Even then, why pipe the file and not just give it to xz?

Answer (score 33):

`xzcat console.img.xz | dd of=/dev/mmcblk0p3 status=progress`

`xz -dc console.img.xz | dd of=/dev/mmcblk0p3 status=progress`

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: I like the use of xzcat here - It's a little simpler and easier to remember

Comment: For anyone curious, on `xz` the `-d` option is for decompression and `-c` is to send the output to stdout (which helps since we are piping the output to `dd` as stdin)